# How to add multiple columns to a table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

How do I add multiple columns in one query statement in PostgreSQL using pgadmin3?

Answer (score 307, accepted):

Try this :

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN col1 int, ADD COLUMN col2 int;
```

Comment: You might want to reference the docs for posterity, `ALTER TABLE [ ONLY ] name [ * ] action [, ... ]`, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: and to set the default value: `ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN col1 int default 0, ADD COLUMN col2 text default 'foo';`

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE  IF EXISTS  TABLEname 
add ADD  COLUMN   IF NOT EXISTS  column_name data_type  [column_constraint];
```

detailed query where column_constraints are optional

Comment: Ouch... Neither of the syntaxes above work in Redshift :-(  

I get errors: 

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," LINE 1: ALTER TABLE x ADD COLUMN col1 int, ADD COLUMN colX int